# How to replace EVERY word in JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace every word in a text for another but couldn't find any of for doing that.

Like this example:

from this>
**hi my name is Robert.**

to this>
**ligh ligh ligh ligh ligh**
(same amount of words)

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define a word? What about  `Foo1`, `_bar` etc...?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
var from = 'hi my name is Robert.';
var to = from.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, 'ligh'); 

// or use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if you want to allow numbers in a word
var to2 = from.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, 'ligh'); 

console.log(to);
```

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Thus for `'hi my name is Robert _ .'` it would fail.

Comment: True! Will update my answer

Comment: It depends how OP defines a *word* - maybe he is fine with e.g. *s1mple*